# window.history.back();return false;" not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
<select id='orginCountryID' onChange='FillSubDropdownlist(this.value)'>
    <option>-- select country --</option>
    <option>Malaysia</option>
    <option>Philippines</option>
</select>

<select id='orginCityID'>
    <option>-- select city/town --</option>
    <option>Kuala Lumpur</option>
    <option>Manila</option>
</select>

<a href="#"  onclick="window.history.back();return false;" class="btngrey"><span>back</span></>
```

It is not working IE11, the city option is missing. When I select a county the city automatically loads. When I click the back button the country option shows up fine, but the city option is missing only in IE, other browsers are working fine.

Comment: Where is that `FillSubDropdownlist()` function you are referring to defined? If the code is set up properly, that part should make the city dropdown box display once you have selected a valid country fom the country dropdown box.

Comment: Also, I think some of the code was cut off (only the first part of the `<a href` was in your code)

Comment: don't use a `<a>` if you're not going to link to another resource. `href="#"` actually *means* something in HTML5, namely "navigate to the top of this document" so if you need what is effectively a button, not a link to the top of the document, use a `<button>` element and then add CSS to make it look exactly how you need it to look (the only reason it looks like a button is browser default styling, all of which is overrulable)

Comment: Did you try window.history.go(-1) instead of back(). I think I had similar problem before.

Comment: yes if i change like this  window.history.go(-1) ....its working in IE but fails in chrome

Comment: FillSubDropdownlist() for mapping country and city that's working fine.but when i click back btn in next page...

Comment: Nvm, just see the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" class="btngrey"><span>back</span></a>
```

Or

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;" class="btngrey"><span>back</span></a>
```

Hope this works.And remember to close your  tag properly